# Suggest printer for printing photomasks for homemade PCBs

Tags: pcb

could you please suggest printer for printer photomasks at home?
Target is to have 0.1x0.1 features or better.

My tests shows that inkjet are pretty bad when working under 0.3x0.3.
So obviously, only lasers left.

Is 1200x1200 worth it? Any experience showing one models better than others? Any specific examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use an old Lexmark Optra R+ on tracing paper. 1200dpi is worth having for finer-pitch stuff but I do routine boards at 600dpi,

Comment: Hmm... Optra R+ seems to have 1200... Why don't use use it for routine boards too?

Comment: Because it's slower, so 600dpi is my default setting for normal paper printing jobs, which is what the printer is used for 99% of the time, and as 600 is fine for most PCBs I don't bother changing it.

Comment: Do you get different results using toner transfer paper?

Answer (score 2):

I get excellent results with a cheap HP inket printer and Mega Electronics Premium Jetstar film - down to 8 mil tracks. I've even done 5 mil as an experiment. It does 1200 dpi.

Comment: [£1.35/sheet](http://www.megauk.com/artwork_films.php) -- expensive, and about par with competition.

Comment: Other film I've tried doesn't work nearly as well. I cut it to size and tape it to a carrier sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Back when we made our own PCBs, we used an HP2100, and printed on translucent acetates. The translucent ones are better because the toner grips it better. It was expensive at £500, but it's still producing perfect prints after 10 years!

It's worth getting a printer capable of 1200x1200 if you're doing SMD.

Comment: I've gotten good (toner-transfer rather than photo) results for .5mm pitch PQFP's from a dirt cheap personal laserjet that claims to be 1200x600. In general, I think what you pay for in printers is mechanics to support high volume usage, large page size, or color; just putting black toner on paper is no longer expensive.